# Javascript Date Object - Different Value in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, date, jsfiddle

This is a simple one I think.

Why do I get 2015-11-04 when I run the following code in JSFiddle (new Date(1451606399999), but when I run the same code in my browser console I get 2015-12-31 (which is the value I'm expecting).

I would have thought any in either case the timezone would be the same as the code is running on the client, and why would timezone make more than a month difference in the date?

```
function test()
{
    var date = new Date(1451606399999);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    var formattedTime = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = formattedTime;
}
```

[JSFiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/msteel9999/j865tjw0/6/)

Comment: Month is zero based, 11= december

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusingly, `date.getMonth()` is 0 based, meaning 0 is January, so it should be `month = date.getMonth()+1`. Also confusingly `date.getDay()` actually returns the day of the week (0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday... etc). The function you're looking for is `date.getDate()`

```
function test(){
    var date = new Date(1451606399999);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    var formattedTime = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    console.log(date);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = formattedTime;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Should have taken more time to check the definitions I guess. Thanks for the answer